# Start Outlook Command Line Switches Parameters And Launch Macro

Tags: vbscript, parameters, outlook, command

I'd like to open outlook via command with parameters and launch macro once is opened...

this code open outlook with parameters

```
outlook.exe /c ipm.note /m "m@m.m&subject=abc&body=123" /a "f:\attach.txt"
```

if I add code to launch a macro, outlook won't open and give me an error...
what's wrong in this code ?

```
outlook.exe /c ipm.note /m "m@m.m,&subject=abc&body=123" /a "f:\attach.txt" /autorun mymacro
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't run a macro using a command-line switch. The only relevant command is /altvba, but that's for loading an alternate VBA project file. There's also no option to pass data as a value to be read by a macro if that's your intent. Perhaps an add-in would be best for your solution?