# How to open Outlook and compose an email (but not send it) on MacOS?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, email, outlook

I am trying to open outlook and then compose an email by adding the 'to' list and 'subject' but stop the process there, as I would want to edit the content specific to the email before sending it.

The following code helps me open Outlook but I don't know how to proceed further with composing a new email:

```
opener ="open" if sys.platform == "darwin" else "xdg-open"
subprocess.call([opener, "/Applications/Microsoft Outlook.app"])
```

The following code works (I think) in Windows, but I am not sure how to use in macOS:

```
import win32com.client as win32
outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.To = 'xzy@email.com' 
mail.Subject = 'Paste subject here' 
mail.Body = 'Paste Body here'     
mail.display(False)�
```

Comment: Since AFAIK the pywin32 modules are only for Windows OS, so the code at the end of your question wouldn't work.

Comment: Relevant [start-outlook-command-line-switches-parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34038609)

Answer (score -1):

This will allow you to send a email with attachment using a Python script.

```
import os
import win32com.client as win32

olApp = win32.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')
olns = olApp.GetNameSpace ('MAPI')

mailItem = olApp.CreateItem(0)
mailItem.Subject = 'Test email with Python'
mailItem.BodyFormat = 1
mailItem.Body = "Test Email"
mailItem.To = 'youremail@gmail.com'

mailItem.Attachments.Add(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 
r"C://Users//xxxxx//Desktop//xxxxx.png"))

mailItem.Display()
mailItem.Save()
mailItem.Send()
```

Comment: Will `win32` work on macOS, as mentioned in the question? Is suspect not.

Comment: It doesn't, almost 100% sure it doesn't work.  I was able to get this to work over the weekend though, after hours of research and videos.